# What is the p12 certificate for iOS and should it be shared?

Tags: ios, ios-provisioning, iphone-developer-program

I have an `iOS Developer Membership` and have hired a developer to make an app for me.  The developer has asked for a  `provisioning profile` and a `p12`.  I've created the provisioning profile but I'm unsure about the p12.  I see how to make the p12 but I'm not sure if I should share this with the developer.  Isn't the p12 the private key?  Is it possible to do ad hoc distribution without sharing the p12 with the developer?  What about when I distribute the app when it is completed, it seems like at some point I will have to share this with the developer?

I've looked [here](https://support.tapatalk.com/threads/export-private-key-p12-file-of-your-distribution-certificate.13788/) about p12 but it doesn't say if it's something you should share or not.

Comment: ideally, just simply have the developer "join your team".  it's pretty simple, google around about it.  it's very amateurish if they want you to give your key so they can log in as you to submit the app - it's silly and leads to hassles later.

Comment: Do you have an individual membership or a company membership?

Comment: @picciano  it's a company membership.  I just want to be able to test the app the developer did for me.  The app is developed already so he has the tools but I guess since he's asking for the p12 we can't do ad-hoc distribution for testing unless I share because he doesn't have a company or personal account.

Comment: @JoeBlow if I let them "join my team" they will be able to access my private certificates that way correct? it seems like I shouldn't share private keys (p12).

Comment: as I just said, best is to simply **add the developer to your team**.  that's the answer.  it's that simple.  if you do that, they will NOT HAVE YOUR PRIVATE KEYS. they will use their own private keys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you created a Company Developer Account, you shouldn't share your certificates. Instead you should invite your developer to your development team.

Unfortunately, Apple requires you to actually be a Company in order to register a Company account, so it's very common to create a personal Apple Developer account instead.

In this kind of accounts, you rights to develop only for you, so Apple needs to make sure that the one that is developing the apps is the one that paid for the account.

If you want to develop with the same Developer Account in two Macs, you will need to share your p12 certificate and private key with your developer (that's the only way to do it). If you just want to allow development in your developer's Mac, he should create a certificate in his computer, send it to you so you can upload it to the Membership Center at [developer.apple.com](http://developer.apple.com), create the certificate and send it to your developer back.

More information about this is available at the [official Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingCertificates/MaintainingCertificates.html).

**EDIT 1: Invite People**

Here're the steps to invite a developer to your Company Apple Developer account:

1. Login with your Agent account to [member center](https://developer.apple.com/membercenter/index.action)
2. Go to People tab:

[image]

3. Go to Invitations section:

[image]

4. Select Invite Person:

[image]

5. Complete your developer's data and assign him Admin role, so he can create certificates and provisioning profiles:

[image]

Comment: it's a company account.

Comment: Ok, login to your account in Member Center, go to People tab, select Invitations, and select Invite Person from there, to send the invitation to your developer. Assign him Admin role, so he can take care of provisioning profile and certificates creation.

Comment: That sounds good but as an Admin will he have access to my certificates?  You said in your answer that I shouldn't share them.

Comment: he'll have access to your public certificates, but he can't do anything with them since he doesn't have the private key for those certificates. When you create a certificate from Keychain, it creates a pair of public and private parts. You upload the public part, but if your developer wants to use the certificate, he needs the private part (which is the one you shouldn't share)

Comment: Ok I think that's what I need to do.  Right now I am the only person in the People tab and I am "Agent".  When I add people as Admins, they can't change my permissions or access company information correct?

Comment: nope, they can't do anything but create developers things (certificates, profiles, new app ids, and add devices). Even if a new Legal agreement comes, you must sign in with the Agent account and approve those agreements.

Comment: I'm just concerned about protecting the account, the developer is in another country and I don't know how long I'll be using them for development.

Comment: sure, that's the way you should handle it! don't worry, Apple takes very seriously their developer accounts protection, and that's why you had to go through a deep process to get your Company account

Comment: Heinrich -- DO NOT GIVE THEM YOUR KEYS.  very simply, add the new developer to your **team**, as Lucas generously explains at great length.  surely this is clear now??